# Maxscript's function to remove degenerative faces in 3DS MAX

Tags: maxscript

How can I call removeDegenerateFaces on particular model? I'm unable to understand what's on autodesk documentation, since it is basically only line below

```
meshop.removeDegenerateFaces <Mesh mesh>
```

http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/MAXScript-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-EF78FA1A-A382-4BED-BA10-7C856A7551A5.htm,topicNumber=d30e365344

let's assume I have object called body, how could I call that function on it?
I tried
`body.removeDegenerateFaces <Mesh mesh>`, but there was: error `'<factor> expected'`..

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question, supposing the object named body is Editable mesh, you can do so by calling

```
meshop.removeDegenerateFaces $body
```

It will return `true` in case there were some and it removed them, `false` otherwise. I suspect, though, that it might not be what you are actually after – providing a detailed description would definitely help.

Comment: What I was after was to remove degenerate faces from model as I stated, because I wanted to export model to cryengine and cry exporter won't allow that with those degenerate faces. It worked, and Thanks again